# Loopback - see data before overwriting in "after save" hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I've seen this question: [Strongloop : Compare old model with the new instance in operation hook 'before save'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323833/strongloop-compare-old-model-with-the-new-instance-in-operation-hook-before-s)

Is there any way to get the data in the DB before the overwriting is done in the `before save` hook? Basically, I want to be able to pass one element to update in a `put` request rather than pass all `required` fields during the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for upsertWithWhere or upsert which does a PATCH rather then a PUT. If you do that and the right row can be identified (you send along the primary ID or identify the row) only the passed along data will be updated/overwritten and the rest will be kept.

That's the easy way, if you want to do something more advanced (like doing modifies on DB before a save) then you just have to access the Model in the before save hook and modify. Remember you can do anything before a save as long as you postpone the "next()" call.

Comment: urgh, I'm being really stupid and using `PUT` method which needs data for all `required` fields. You're right, the `PATCH` method just updates the field that's passed, thanks for pointing out my stupidness!